# An inconsistence in a proof by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Here is the quote from textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech.

---

> Let $(A_1,<_1)$ and $(A_2,<_2)$ be linearly ordered sets and $A_1 \cap A_2=\emptyset$. The relation $<$ on $A=A_1 \cup A_2$ defined by $$a<b \text{ if and only if } a,b\in A_1 \text{ and } a<_1 b $$ $$\text{or } a,b\in A_2 \text{ and } a<_2 b $$ $$\text{or } a\in A_1,b\in A_2$$ is a linear ordering.
>
> Proof. This is Exercise 5.6 in Chapter 2, so again we leave it to the reader.
>
> The set $A$ is ordered by putting all elements of $A_1$ before all elements of $A_2$. We say that the linearly ordered set $(A,<)$ is the *sum* of the linearly ordered sets $(A_1,<_1)$ and $(A_2,<_2)$.
>
> Notice that the order type of the sum does not depend on the particular orderings $(A_1,<_1)$ and $(A_2,<_2)$, only on their types (see Exercise 4.1). As an example, the linearly ordered set $(\Bbb Z,<)$ of all integers is similar to the sum of the linearly ordered sets $(\Bbb N,<^{-1})$ and $(\Bbb N,<)$ ($<$ denotes the usual ordering of numbers by size).

---

First, the authors define the $sum$ of $(A_1,<_1)$ and $(A_2,<_2)$ with the condition that $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$, but at the end they give an example of $(\Bbb Z,<)$, which is the sum of $\Bbb N,<^{-1})$ and $(\Bbb N,<)$. It's clear that $\Bbb N \cap \Bbb N=\Bbb N\neq \emptyset$.

---

Please help me reconcile this discrepancy!

[image]

Comment: Thats no reason for alarm, you can take their disjoint union instead. I agree that what you're saying is kinda true but you can easily correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are not disjoint, then choose $B_1$ and $B_2$
which are disjoint, and of the same cardinalities as $A_1$ ans $A_1$,
and put orders on then so that $(B_1,<_1')$ is order-isomorphic to $(A_1,<_1)$
and $(B_2,<_2')$ is order-isomorphic to $(A_2,<_2)$. Then take the 
order-sum of the $(B_i,<_i')$.

This is a standard dodge in set theory, when you'd like disjoint sets, but
don't actually have them. It's the sort of thing that causes advocates
of category-theoretic foundations of maths to snigger.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, in this context something like $(-\Bbb N,<)$ instead of $(\Bbb N,<^{-1})$ might we more appropriate, in the light of the formulation of the lemma. However, it is clear (and mentioned) that at least the order type of the sum depends only on the order type of the (for the moment, disjoint) summands, and this allows us to speak of the sum  (not as concrete ordered set, but as order type) indirectly also for cases where the summand sets are not disjoint.

More formally, we could define $A=(A_1\times\{1\})\cup (A_2\times\{2\})$ in the lemma in order to ensure disjointness in all situations.